# how to achieve this result

Tags: python, list

I am working on small project using Python 2.6. Finally my list is like this.

```
data = ['1:Rammmm,mmmm', '2:surr.rrrrr', '3:Sam ttttt',
'1:qqqq qqqqqqq', '2:wwwwwwwwwww', '3:eeeeeeeee','4:tttttttt',
'1:zzzzzzzzzzzzz', '2:xxxxxxxxx']
```

Here, I want to display all 1's in one line, all 2's in one line, etc., with pipe"|" as separator. It should be like this, sorting only by the number.

```
{Rammmm,mmmm|qqqq qqqqqqq|zzzzzzzzzzzzz}
{surr.rrrrr|wwwwwwwwwww|xxxxxxxxx}
{Sam ttttt|eeeeeeeee}
{tttttttt}
```

How can this be achieved in Python?

Answer (score 3):

See my other solution as I believe it is better than this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173807/1219006

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = ['1:Rammmm,mmmm', '2:surr.rrrrr', '3:Sam ttttt',
'1:qqqq qqqqqqq', '2:wwwwwwwwwww', '3:eeeeeeeee','4:tttttttt',
'1:zzzzzzzzzzzzz', '2:xxxxxxxxx']
>>> sorted_data = sorted(((int(x),y) for x,y in (el.split(':') for el in data)),key=itemgetter(0))
>>> for k,v in groupby(sorted_data,key=itemgetter(0)):
        print '{' + '|'.join(text for num,text in v) + '}'


{Rammmm,mmmm|qqqq qqqqqqq|zzzzzzzzzzzzz}
{surr.rrrrr|wwwwwwwwwww|xxxxxxxxx}
{Sam ttttt|eeeeeeeee}
{tttttttt}
```

Test

```
>>> data = ['1:Rameshrrrrrrr', '2:Sureshmmmmmm', '3:Samkkkkkkkk', '1:tttttttttt', '2:wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww', '3:yyyyyyyyy', '4:gggggggggg', '1:qqqqqqqqqqq', '2:hhhhhhhhh']
>>> sorted_data = sorted(((int(x),y) for x,y in (el.split(':') for el in data)),key=itemgetter(0))
>>> for k,v in groupby(sorted_data,key=itemgetter(0)):
        print '{' + '|'.join(text for num,text in v) + '}'


{Rameshrrrrrrr|tttttttttt|qqqqqqqqqqq}
{Sureshmmmmmm|wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww|hhhhhhhhh}
{Samkkkkkkkk|yyyyyyyyy}
{gggggggggg}
```

Comment: This is working perfectly.But Sorting should be numbers.all 1's first,all 2's second,then 3's.But not text Ex:{Sam ttttt|eeeeeeeee}
i want like this,But above code sorting text also(Which i don't want)
please correct it this is my mailid:ramesh.chowdary03@gmail.com

Comment: Ok i added, `key=itemgetter(0)` to the `sorted` function so now it only sorts by the number.

Comment: list = ['1:Rameshrrrrrrr', '2:Sureshmmmmmm', '3:Samkkkkkkkk', '1:tttttttttt', '2:wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww', '3:yyyyyyyyy', '4:gggggggggg',  '1:qqqqqqqqqqq', '2:hhhhhhhhh']

Removed "key=itemgetter(0)" and tried still its sorting text also,i want something like this.

{Rameshrrrrrrr|tttttttttt|qqqqqqqqqqq}
{Sureshmmmmmm|wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww|hhhhhhhhh}
{Samkkkkkkkk|yyyyyyyyy}

Comment: Why did you remove that? I tried it with the updated code and i got your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You will need:

- A way to split apart each string into the number part and the other part
- A way to convert the number part into an integer
- A way to collect all the various parts.  You need a list of all the other parts that have the same number part.
- Loop over all the strings in your list and collect everything.
- A way to join together the other parts to make the final result.

A good way to find out what you can do in Python is to go to the Python prompt and type `help(something)`.  Replace "something" with what you want help for.  Try these:

`help(str.split)`

`help(str.join)`

And I'll suggest that you convert to integer by calling `int()`.  Like this:

```
x = "3"
n = int(x)  # n is now the integer value 3
```

And I suggest you consider using a `dict` to collect things.  You will have more than one value per dict key... you need to either join them together in the `dict` or make some sort of a list for each one in the `dict`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

l = ['1:Rammmm,mmmm', '2:surr.rrrrr', '3:Sam ttttt', '1:qqqq qqqqqqq', '2:wwwwwwwwwww', 3:eeeeeeeee','4:tttttttt', '1:zzzzzzzzzzzzz', '2:xxxxxxxxx']

l = [ x.split(':') for x in l ]

d ={}
for k, v in l:
  try: 
    d[k]
  except:
    d[k] = []
  d[k].append(v)

l = d.values()
l = [ "|".join(x) for x in l ]
```

Comment: Instead of doing try: d[k], you should use a `defaultdict`. Also dictionaries are unordered so your output may or may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way of doing it

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = ['1:Rammmm,mmmm', '2:surr.rrrrr', '3:Sam ttttt',
'1:qqqq qqqqqqq', '2:wwwwwwwwwww', '3:eeeeeeeee','4:tttttttt',
'1:zzzzzzzzzzzzz', '2:xxxxxxxxx']
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for num, text in (el.split(':') for el in data):
        d[int(num)].append(text)


>>> for key in sorted(d):
        print '{' + '|'.join(d[key]) + '}'


{Rammmm,mmmm|qqqq qqqqqqq|zzzzzzzzzzzzz}
{surr.rrrrr|wwwwwwwwwww|xxxxxxxxx}
{Sam ttttt|eeeeeeeee}
{tttttttt}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this for obtaining desire output :

```
l=[]
for ls in data:
    l.append(ls[:1])
m=set(l)
for i in m:
    str=''
    for ls in data:
        if i==ls[:1]:
            str=str+ls[3:]+"|"
    print '{'+str+'}'
```

Comment: This only works if there is a one digit number. Also a `set` is unordered so this may or may not produce the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

May be this variant would be even simplier:

```
data = ['1:Rammmm,mmmm', '2:surr.rrrrr', '3:Sam ttttt',
        '1:qqqq qqqqqqq', '2:wwwwwwwwwww', '3:eeeeeeeee','4:tttttttt',
        '1:zzzzzzzzzzzzz', '2:xxxxxxxxx']

d = dict()
for item in data:
    k, v = item.split(':')
    # if d already has list at key 'k', append to it; 
    # otherwise, create list, and append to newly created
    d.setdefault(k,list()).append(v)

# now print formatted list in order of sorted keys (1,2,3,4)
for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    print '{' + '|'.join(d[k]) + '}'
```